# Is a lock mandatory when using tasks?

Tags: c#, locking

I am currently developing an application in WinForm C# to display values from a device, but I need to find the correct way.

I start a task which is an endless loop in `Mainform` constructor. This task is reading data from a device and writing it in shared variables.

`Mainform` is reading these shared variables to display data.

As the task is only writing and `Mainform` is only reading shared variables do I need to use lock instruction on shared variables?
What is the risk if don't use Lock?

Below is the starting of the task in `Mainform` constructor.

Thank you!

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            ReadDeviceData();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => 
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message +"\n\n"+ e.StackTrace, "task exception\n"));
        }                        

        Thread.Sleep(200);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thread safety is a huge topic and one you will need to start researching. if you could narrow down what you are reading and writing it would help to give you an answer... in short though, if shared, its not atomic or immutable, its not thread safe or you are afraid of stale values, a lock is probably what you need

Comment: You have a number of issue with this code. Running a `while(true)` loop in a task isn't a great way to go. Neither is just catching every exception. Calling `Thread.Sleep(200)` is generally bad. And finally `ReadDeviceData()` must be updating the UI from a non-UI thread, which shouldn't be done. We're happy to help you fix your code but you should post a [mcve] so that we can replicate what you're seeing by being able to run your code.

Answer (score 0):

If only one thread writing to variable then you don't have to lock. Lock is recommended when you simultaneously try to write to one variable.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

Answer (score 0):

It depends `ReadDeviceData`.

Reading `int`, `bool` or `object('s reference)` is safe in C#'s memory model.

In other cases, you may consider to use `ReaderWriterLock` or `ReaderWriterLock` which is more suitable with your situation.

Answer (score 0):

The `lock` keyword does not lock variables. It defines a portion of code that can only be executed on one thread at a time. For example, of these two code blocks, only one could be executing at any moment, and only on one thread:

```
lock (lockObject)
{
    this.A = random.Next();
    this.B = random.Next();
    this.C = this.A + this.B;
}

lock (lockObject)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}+{1}={2}", this.A, this.B, this.C);
}
```

So at any given moment, only one thread is either reading or writing to the member variables A, B, and C.

What would happen if we removed the locks? The operating system uses pre-emptive multithreading, so you cannot ensure that your code won't be interrupted at any moment, in between any two lines of code (and sometimes even during one). So the second code block, for example, could occur between any two lines in the first code block. Let's see...

```
this.A = random.Next();
this.B = random.Next();
Console.WriteLine("{0}+{1}={2}", this.A, this.B, this.C);
this.C = this.A + this.B;
```

As you can clearly see, this program would be bad at math.

That being said, we can mitigate the issue without any locks by being clever about how we assign things.

```
var results = new SomeClass
{
    A = random.Next(),
    B = random.Next()
};
results.C = results.A + results.B;
this.LatestResults = results;
```

Now the only variable that is shared (since each thread gets its own local variables) is `LatestResults`.  Which can be updated in a single, atomic operation. In this case, no lock is required.

Answer (score 0):

You should always lock when reading **and** writing to shared data, unless you are an expert in lock-free multithreaded programming, in which case you whouldn't ask this question. Threading without locks has many caveats, and you should better be safe than sorry.

Keep in mind that uncontested locks are cheap. You can lock one million times in one second and your CPU won't even notice. Locks become a bottleneck when they are contested. If your UI accesses the shared data sporadically and not in a tight loop, you should have no problems using locks. No reason to search for a lock-free solution in that case.